# Java Open a JFrame relative to the position of a button (menu like behaviour)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, position, jframe

I am trying to implement expand functionality like in below example, however instead of a menu I am using a JFrame which contains more sophisticated GUI elements. 
[image]
The problem I run into is that if I move the parent window which contains the button below which the frame should appear, I can not adjust my custom JFrame to open each time relative to the position of that button

initially I simply used

```
myCustomFrame.setLocation(myButton.getX(), (myButton.getY() + 73));
```

but this obviously doesn't work if I change move the parent window

After that I tried

```
myCustomFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(myButton);
```

but in this case it appears at the top of the button... I adjust the position for a particular case, but this is not a solution.

So I am trying to get the same behavior as menus have, such  that the position of the JFrame is automatically adjusted.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using `myButton.getLocationOnScreen()`? That way no matter where you move the jFrame containing the button you will always get the Point of your button measured from the top left corner of the screen.

You could alter your original method something like this:

```
myCustomFrame.setLocation(myButton.getLocationOnScreen().x, (myButton.getLocationOnScreen().y + 73));
```

Comment: I'm getting IllegalComponentStateException exception
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location`

Comment: The parent is showing but it says `component must be showing on the screen to determine its location`

Comment: Is the component visible? Try set the components background color to red so you can make sure.

Comment: In the parent jframe I have only two things a jpanel and a jbutton both are visible. when I press jbutton to open new undecorated jframe that's location is according to jbutton.getLocationOnScreen();
it show the exception.

Comment: In that case you probably need to initialize and show the new frame first, and then set the location as shown in the answer.

Comment: when I try show show undecorated jframe first its shows the same exception. it make sense because I'm getting jbutton's location that is not visible yet.

Comment: But on the other case when the other jframe is visible from which I'm calling the undecorated jframe it does not make sense to show exception.