# How to mimic the behavior of JPopupMenu with JDialog?

Tags: java, swing

I'm implementing an "in app" search engine with Swing and I want it to behave exactly like Windows 10's search box.

The search box should:

- Open above and to the right of the search button, touching the button's edge.
- Have the focus when open.
- Close (if open) on a press of the search button.
- Close (if open) when pressing with the mouse anywhere out of the search box.

It was perfect if JPopUpMenu could have JDialog as it's child but since it can't I need to implement the behaviors from scratch (or do I?).

This is my first time using Swing and I'm having difficulties implementing everything by myself.
I tried looking for examples online but I couldn't find much helpful information.

Is there a workaround to the fact that JPopUpMenu can't host JDialog?
Are there examples of implementing the behaviors I described?

Thanks

===============================Edit============================
Thanks for the comments so far. I've managed to get the behavior I wanted except one issue.

The following code creates a frame with a button:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
    mainWindow.setSize(420,420);
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);

    JFrame popUp = new JFrame();
    popUp.setSize(210, 210);

    JButton button = new JButton("button");
    mainWindow.add(button);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!button.isSelected()){
                button.setSelected(true);
                popUp.setVisible(true);
            }
            else{
                button.setSelected(false);
                popUp.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });

    popUp.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            popUp.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
```

When I click the button, a pop-up window appears and if I click out of the main window the pop up disappear but then when I want to re-open the pop-up I need to press the button twice.

How can I get the button to operate correctly when the pop-up was closed due to lose of focus?

Comment: You cannot add a JDialog to anything, as it is tied to a OS native peer window.  You might want to look into using JWindow for what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Not sure what your issues are. You can easily create a JDialog with any components your want. You add logic to your button to check if the dialog is visible or not and then do appropriate processing. You make the dialog non-modal so you can give focus to any component on the dialog once it is visible. You can add a WindowListener to the dialog and handle the windowDeactivated event to close the dialog. If you need more help post an [mre] showing what you have done and ask one specific question at a time.

Comment: [`JPopupMenu#setInvoker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html)?

Comment: If you want JDialogue behaviour then use a JDialogue and simply position it on screen [relative to your menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056821/java-open-a-jframe-relative-to-the-position-of-a-button-menu-like-behaviour), or if you can just insert buttons or similar into your JPopupMenu using `yourPopup.insert(component, index);` and make the buttons perform the relevant action.

Answer (score 0):

Your "solution" is very brittle.  Try moving the main `JFrame` before left-clicking on the `JButton`.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.  Study the rest of the tutorial.

I created a main `JFrame` that pops up a `JDialog`.  I put the close `JButton` on the `JDialog`.  The `JDialog` is modal, meaning you cannot access the main `JFrame` while the `JDialog` is visible.

You can place the `JDialog` anywhere you wish on the screen.  Normally, you have a `JDialog` appear in the center of the parent `JFrame`.  That's where users expect a dialog to appear.  I placed the `JDialog` towards the upper left, just to show you how it's done.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PopupExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new PopupExample().createAndShowGUI());
    }

    private JFrame mainWindow;

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        mainWindow = new JFrame("Main Window");
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainWindow.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(200, 200, 200, 200));

        JButton button = new JButton("button");
        panel.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                createAndShowDialog(mainWindow);
            }
        });

        return panel;
    }

    private void createAndShowDialog(JFrame frame) {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog", true);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        dialog.add(createDialogPanel(dialog), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        dialog.pack();
        
        // Here's where you set the location of the JDialog relative
        // to the main JFrame
        Point origin = frame.getLocation();
        dialog.setLocation(new Point(origin.x + 30, origin.y + 30));
        
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createDialogPanel(JDialog dialog) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));

        JButton button = new JButton("Close");
        panel.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I feel that my question wasn't understood. My question (after the edit) was "How to create a JFrame that opens and closes at the press of a button and also closes when it loses focus?"